Enemy Agro Not Working and variables all assigned
I am working on a game in Unity and my code for the Ranged Enemy's Agro isn't working. The script is for an enemy which shoots projectiles from a bow. If the enemy is close enough to the player it will shoot or walk towards the player until it is close enough to shoot. However, it will not move closer to the player when it is too far to shoot. All print statements are shown in the console. I have assigned all variables for the code yet the Enemy is still not chasing the player when he isn't nearby.I have also attached the values put for the code.
Code in C#:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RangedAgro : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float distanceToShoot;

    public float distance;

    private Transform player;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public int speed;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform bulletPos;
    private float timer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);
        if (distance <= distanceToShoot)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            if(timer > 2){
                timer = 0;
                Shoot();
            }
        }
        else if(distance > distanceToShoot)
        {
            Chase();
            print("TRUE");
        }
        if(player.transform.position.x > transform.position.x) transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        if(player.transform.position.x < transform.position.x) transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(bullet, bulletPos.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    void Chase()
    {
        if (player.position.x > transform.position.x)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            print("YES");
        }else if (player.position.x < transform.position.x)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
            print("NO");
        }
    }
}

I tried making the else statement more specific by adding distance > distanceToShoot and also added some debugging by adding print statements.

I have tried your code and it is working fine. Agro is chasing the player. Are you sure you have changed the variable speed on the inspector?

@mejan, I have assigned all variables and have attached a screenshot of the values I input.

Do print("yes") and print("no") get shown when you enter and exit the distance? If they do, but the agro is not moving, I think there might be an issue with your rigidbody or the scene that prevents it from moving. I created a new and simple game object for agro when I tried your code, and it worked. So, maybe you need to test it with a simple game object and a new clean scene too.

Thank you @mejan for solving it! I had turned on freeze y in the constraints.

Happy to help..
